# StreamReader fails to detect BOM

Tags: c#

I have the following piece of code:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.GetEncoding("shift-jis"), true)) {
    mCertainFileIsUTFFormat = !sr.CurrentEncoding.Equals(Encoding.GetEncoding("shift-jis"));
    mCodingFromBOM = sr.CurrentEncoding;

    String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
    return line.Split('\n');
}
```

Basically reading a file and assuming Shift-Jis if there is no BOM.  Alas, this method is always, no matter what, returning Shift-JIS encoding, even if the file in question has a BOM within it.  Am I doing something wrong here or perhaps there is a known issue?  I could always open the file binary and do the work myself, but this is supposed to do what I want :)

Comment: Make sure to call `Read` of any kind - it will not detect encoding *before* reading. [CurrentEncoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.currentencoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - "The value can be different after the first call to any Read method of StreamReader, since encoding autodetection is not done until the first call to a Read method."

Comment: Hmm.  let me try that. :)

Comment: You sir earn +1 internets for the day.  Make that an answer and I'll set it as solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call `Read` of any kind - `StreamReader` will not detect encoding *before* reading. I.e. get encoding after your `ReadToEnd` call:

```
  String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
  mCodingFromBOM = sr.CurrentEncoding;
```

Info: [StreamReader.CurrentEncoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.currentencoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The value can be different after the first call to any Read` method of StreamReader, since encoding autodetection is not done until the first call to a Read method.